# IntelliJ IDEA 15 Play 2.4 reverse routing method parameter "string cannot be applied to java.lang.String"

Tags: playframework-2.4, intellij-15

I use IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4 to develop a Java Play! 2.4.4 application. Since a few months (I think it was because of an IntelliJ update, but not 100% sure) the following problem occurs:

Whenever I call a reverse route from a controller that takes a String as a parameter, the parameter is displayed as an error with the following message:

> methodName (string) in ReverseMyController cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Here's a code example:

```
public Result myAction(String myId) {
    // Do something...

    // Redirect back to referrer
    flash("success", "Action was a success");
    if(!myId.isEmpty()) return redirect(controllers.routes.MyController.showItem(myId));
    return redirect(controllers.routes.MyController.itemList(1));
}
```

In this example, the parameter `myId` passed to the method `showItem` would be error highlighted, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHcEU.png)

I already tried fiddling with the Project Structure settings and searched Google, but to no avail. I hope somebody is able to help me with this, my OCD-self would really appreciate having a code base with no error hints again ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I meet the same issue as what you said. I think it is a bug of the IDEA 15.0.4,  Have you tried to change to the older version before 15.0.4?

Comment: Thanks, I'll file a bug report in that case. I wasn't sure if it's a bug or a config problem because no one else seemed to have the same problem thus far.

Comment: There was already an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9688 Hope it gets resolved soon :)

Comment: I download IDEA 2016.1 and update scala plugin to 3.0.0, the error message disappeared.

Comment: Same for me :) but I had to replace all occurrences of `controllers.routes.MyController` with `routes.MyController` for whatever reason.

Comment: @RaphaelMäder Yes, I also use routes.MyController.:)

Comment: I downloaded IDEA 2016.1 and updated scala plugin to 3 but the error message didin't change. Then updated to IDEA 2016.2 but the message remains the same:(

Comment: Is there any more suggestion @deezh ?

Comment: You have marked the target/scala-xx/routes/main directory as the Sources Root? if not, please try @erdemlal

Comment: @deezh yep, i added but didn't work, i changed `controllers.routes.MyController` with `routes.MyController` like raphael suggested and worked for me too:)

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer does not solve the problem that is why I am answering this old question.

I had the same problem with **Play** `2.5.4` and **InteliJ** `2016.1.3`

I removed the type (`String`) from route declaration in routes file and **InteliJ** stopped highlighting it as error.

Change following:

`GET    /path/:string_arg       controllers.MyController.myMethod(string_arg: String)`

To

`GET    /path/:string_arg       controllers.MyController.myMethod(string_arg)`

and it works fine.

Comment: It answered the question for Play 2.4.x, but you're indeed correct that your answer solves it for Play 2.5.x. Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions for play 2.6? Tried this but did not have an impact. I'm using InteliJ 2017.1 with Play 2.6.